# SAP GUI Security popup

Tags: vba, ms-access, sap-gui

I am writing a program that uses Microsoft access to run a report and then export the results to an excel file. The whole program works fine except when the program is exporting the file. I receive a SAP GUI Security popup like this:

> The system is trying to replace the file XXXXXX
>
> Do you want to allow this?
>
> `[Allow]`     `[Deny]`
> [image: allow program to overwrite a file]

The VBA code in access pauses while this popup is in place. From what I understand, the VBA code will not interact with this popup. This code might be used by multiple people with different settings so I would like to interact with this popup with VBA code if possible. My question is: is there a way to click allow on this popup using only VBA code? or will Microsoft Access not interact with the popup because it is an SAP security popup?

Comment: one thing I forgot; while stepping through the program, when this popup comes up, there is no pointer in VBA telling me which line of code is running and i cannot modify any code. This tells me that the code is running however it is not dealing with a line of code.

Comment: Please share the actual code. You can step through the code line by line to see which line triggers it.

Comment: session.findbyid("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "folderPath"
        session.findbyid("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "fileName"
    
        session.findbyid("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 19
        session.findbyid("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

Comment: the popup is triggered by the last line of code, the button press